# Repeated measures variance analysis in R

Tags: r, variance, repeated-measures

(Cross-posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257206/repeated-measures-variance-analysis-in-r))

I have some data that look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(hormone = c(65.1, 32.8, 29.6, 42.3),
                 medication = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                 lab = c('One', 'Two', 'One', 'Two'))
```

(it's actually much larger; this is just an idea of the format)

I need to analyze the variance of data with Medication A vs. Medication B. Normally I would just do a variance test, but I need to control for the different labs, and I do not know how. What test allows me to compare the variance among hormone levels based on medication while adjusting for lab?